# Is there an easy way to learn which kwargs are valid for a method or a function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyword-argument

I am generally having a hard time while finding the **valid** `**kwargs` for a function or a method. For example let us consider the following example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xticks(ticks=None, labels=None, **kwargs)
```

As you can see this `.xticks()` method accepts `**kwargs`. In order to find the valid `**kwargs`, I generally write some random `kwarg` such as `plt.xticks(font_size=14)` and then I generally get and `AttributeError`. For this case the error is the following `AttributeError: 'Text' object has no property 'font_size'`. Then I go to the documentation and find `Text` object, and then if I am lucky, I find the valid `**kwargs` in the documentation and finally I fix my code as `plt.yticks(fontsize=14)` where `fontsize` is the valid `kwarg` for this method. I always follow a similar path like this.

However I found this process so tedious and long. I am looking for an easy and quick solution **in general**. Is there a quick way to find valid `kwargs` or should I do this process or another similar process everytime in order to find valid `kwargs` for a method or a function?

Comment: No, and there *can't* be a fully general, automatic way. It would involve reading and understanding the implementation code. That's why documenting your own code is so important. If you find another project's documentation inadequate, you should take it up with the authors - Stack Overflow is not tech support.

Comment: In most IDE's you can `ctrl-click` on the method name to go to the implementation of said method. Well commented/documented packages will have explanation in the code for the method. Otherwise you'll have to actually disect the method itself to see which variables it uses without being declared. Those would be the `kwargs`... This is how I deal with methods that lack external documentation.

Comment: Thank you guys, I get it.